# Why is being able to run alert() function considered unsafe?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I am looking into: https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet

Most of the examples are given with `alert('XSS')` - but how is that a problem?

As far as I know, alert is a nuisance, at most... Do they imply the alert method can be replaced with something malicious? If so, what is a method on that level that can actually do damage?

Or do they imply that alert can be used maliciously itself, by providing certain parameters.

Clarification: as written, I don't consider alert itself unsafe. I am interested in what makes it a good demo for unsafe methods allowed to run.

For example: how would I change `<BODY ONLOAD=alert('XSS')>` to something malicious?

Again, the answer can't be "you **can** change...". I **tried** to change and couldn't get anything interesting instead of alert(). 
Say I want to browse to google.com or execute google.com/xss.js? (obviously this script does not exist... I don't think I am supposed to give links to a place that might actually host real scripts in it!)

Comment: No, the alert itself won’t do any damage, that is only used for demonstration purposes. It illustrates the fact _that_ JS code can be inserted into a site, and that in itself basically _is_ a XSS vulnerability already. Whether the exact code was an alert or something else, does not matter that much at this point.

Comment: In other words, imagine somebody wanted to warn you that the front door to your appratment is unlocked. They get in and leave a sticky note saying "Hey, it was unlocked". The note is not bad. The fact that it's present confirms the problem.

Comment: Re edit: You put malicious code where `alert('XSS')` is. ‍♂️ Malicious things you could do depend very much on what the website is. Something significantly malicious an attacker could do with code injection on BBC News is very different to what would be malicious on GMail.

Comment: Re latest edit: "Say I want to browse to google.com" — We can't tell why your effort doesn't work without a [mcve].

Comment: "execute google.com/xss.js" — What does that mean? The URL points to a 404 error.

Comment: I also can`t follow what this should result in? If you could inject code to e.g. Amazon it could send auth infos of a victim also browsing through Amazon to your server. The victim wont recognize it but you silently received them. Please read the link I provided in my answer to understand what XSS stands for as I think thats the mean problem here.

Comment: I know what XSS stands for (enough for this question). About "execute js - what does that mean?" - I think that's just being a little rude :) It's totally your right to say what you feel but unless there's some weird use case for writing a program other than to execute it (even demo programs in books are "executable" in an abstract way), then I just think you are trying to argue and I will ignore you from now on, thank for your time so far

Comment: as for getting 404 - obviously I wouldn't link to an actual js file that you don't know if I own or not? And then someone can interpret this as me trying to propagate my virus over SE... The same with giving a non-existing address - someone could register that... I think it's safe to assume for now google are not going to place an xss.js file on their main page :)

Comment: Since you seem really stuck on "what can we do with JavaScript code", here is an interesting illustration - [create a botnet from infected browsers while tracking what they do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI). But that's a bit of an extreme example. You can still just steal all cookies and send them to yourself, then attempt to hijack the user's session. Or capture all keystrokes. [Maybe just have a password keylogger](https://jsbin.com/nedoketeyu/1/edit?html,console,output). If you're on Amazon, make an order via the user for your wishlist. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The alert function is just for demonstrational purposes here. It shows that Javascript code was able to be executed via an XSS attack. Learn more about XSS and what it means here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/.

The answer to your question "Do they imply the alert method can be replaced with something malicious?" is therefore: yes. A attacker could replace it with any attack code he likes which will be executed on the victims device like sending secrets to the attackers host or getting part of a botnet.

However I cannot get what you mean with "then surely a beginner like me isn't the actual problem" as this list targets programming beginners in not doing any of these mistakes enabling an attacker easily doing something harmful to your site and all your clients.

Answer (score 1):

> Do they imply the alert method can be replaced with something malicious?

Yes, XSS is a method for [arbitrary code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution).

> What is a method on that level that can actually do damage?

- Prompt downloads for malicious browser extensions
- Steal passwords, session cookies, credit cards, or other sensitive information
- Further propagate the malicious code to other victims like a computer virus
- Cause the victim's browser to perform illegal activities on the attacker's behalf

  - Several victims at once could flood requests to a particular server in order to perform a [Denial-of-service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)
  - Victims' browsers could be used to connect to shady websites

There are so many possibilities.

Comment: I tried to change and couldn't get anything interesting instead of alert().
Say I want to browse to google.com or execute google.com/xss.js?

Comment: @DraxDomax _"And then someone can interpret this as me trying to propagate my virus over SE..."_ [You're not owed anything beyond an `alert()`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287348/1541563). Nobody here is going to prove that XSS works by providing you with _actually_ malicious code. If you're simply trying to learn how to prevent this vulnerability, there is nothing to be gained from knowledge of specific examples of malicious code.